# bind the click event after unbind

Tags: jquery

I am unbinding the click event of a button on the same button click. I want to bind the above button click again on some other button click. But it is not working.

```
    $("#showSelection").bind("click", function () {
    alert("in");
    //unbinding the button click
    $('#showSelection').unbind('click');
    });


   $("#kendowindow").click(function(){
     alert("in2"); 
     //want to bind the click event again but not working     
     $('#showSelection').bind('click');           
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really just rebind it, you'll have to add the entire callback function once more.

To make that easier you can use a named function, and for newer versions of jQuery you should be using `on()` and `off()`, and there's even `one()` if you just want the event handler to fire once per element, and as you're using ID's, you only have one matching element, so :

```
function doStuff() {
    alert("in");
});

$("#showSelection").one("click", doStuff);

$("#kendowindow").on('click', function(){
     alert("in2"); 
     $("#showSelection").off('click').one("click", doStuff);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .one() in order to run your first click event only once:

```
$("#showSelection").one("click", function(){
    alert("in"); 
}); 

$("#kendowindow").click(function(){
    alert("in2"); 
    $("#showSelection").on("click", function(){
        alert("new event bound"); 
    });      
});
```

However, I am not sure exactly what the scenario is that you are trying to accomplish. With this code, if the user clicks the kendowindow FIRST, then it will be assigning a second event to your showSelection click. I'm not sure if that is what you want or not.

Comment: Look at the answer from @adeneo. If you are re-binding the same event, you are best off creating a function that you can call, so that you don't have to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named function as follows:

```js
function bindUnbind() {
    console.log("in");
    //unbinding the button click
    $(this).unbind('click');
}

$("#showSelection").bind("click",bindUnbind);


$("#kendowindow").click(function(){
     console.log("in2"); 
     //want to bind the click event again but not working     
     $('#showSelection').unbind('click').bind('click',bindUnbind);           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showSelection">Show Selection</div>

<div id="kendowindow">Kendo Window</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :)